# What is the story with Removed symbols?

Tags: symbols, assignment, clear

The system function [`Remove`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Remove.html) evidently exists primarily to turn a fatal problem into an annoying one, by giving the user a (rather blunt) instrument with which to resolve symbol clashes. Presumably, it works by removing the entry for a given symbol from whatever internal table *Mathematica* uses to look them up by name. However, there can be some interesting consequences when you have a reference to a symbol that you later `Remove`. First, we need to set up a symbol that we will remove, and give another symbol a reference to it:

```
In[1]:= y = 3
Out[1]= 3

In[2]:= x := y

In[3]:= x
Out[3]= 3

In[4]:= OwnValues[x]
Out[4]= {HoldPattern[x] :> y}
```

And then we can remove it:

```
In[5]:= Remove[y]

In[6]:= x
Out[6]= Removed["y"]
```

Now, we have `Removed["y"]`, which is the ghost of the symbol we just bludgeoned to death. However, contrary to appearances, `Removed` is not the head of the expression:

```
In[7]:= x // Head
Out[7]= Symbol
```

It's still a symbol. It appears to just have had all its values cleared when it was `Remove`'d. However, you need an elaborate incantation to contact a symbol that's moved on into the spirit world in order to verify this:

```
In[8]:= OwnValues[x]
Out[8]= {HoldPattern[x] :> Removed["y"]}

In[9]:= ReleaseHold[Hold[OwnValues[x]] /. OwnValues[x]]
Out[9]= {}
```

That's OK, though, because I can still give new values to the removed symbol!

```
In[10]:= With[{yy = x},
          yy = 17]
Out[10]= 17

In[11]:= ReleaseHold[Hold[OwnValues[x]] /. OwnValues[x]]
Out[11]= {HoldPattern[Removed[y]] :> 17}
```

So, what *can't* you do with a removed symbol that you can do with an ordinary symbol? And is there any reliable programmatic way to check whether a symbol really has been removed, seeing that it has a perfectly ordinary `Symbol` head? I suppose you can hack something together with `StringMatchQ`, but that just feels wrong and it's tough to get the evaluation order right if the removed symbol might have `OwnValues`.

Comment: It gets even more interesting with more than one removal. An example: `y=3;x:=y;x2:=y;x==x2` gives `True`. So far nothing unexpected; after all, both `x` and `x2` evaluate to `Removed[y]`. However now write `x3=y;Remove[y];x==x3` and you'll get `Removed[y] == Removed[y]`. Also `SameQ[x,x2]` gives `True` while `SameQ[x,x3]` gives `False`. That is, Mathematica still tracks the fact whether two `Removed` symbols are the same removed symbol or not although even the `FullForm` is the same for both removed symbols. On the other hand, `Order[x,x3]` gives `0`.

Comment: Oops, I just notice that I omitted something crucial in my previous comment, without which it makes no sense at all! The first code fragment in the example should of course read: `y=3;x:=y;x2:=y;Remove[y];x==x2` — note the addition of `Remove[y]`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Some observations on `Removed`

`Removed` is not a normal head, but rather a print form. Consider a definition

```
x := y
```

Once we `Remove` the `y`, we invalidate `x` in a subtle but permanent way - reintroducing the `y` into the session won't help. `Remove` is really a rather special-purpose destructuve operation, aimed more at removing auto-generated symbols. In a system of inter-connected functions (possibly from different packages), for this reason `Remove` is safe only if nothing depends on the symbol being removed. Resolving shadowing is the only mainstream (frequent, non-advanced) application of `Remove` I am aware of.

I learned from the book of David Wagner ("Power programming with Mathematica",page 251), that while the removed symbol is printed (and has a `FullForm`) as `Removed["sym"]`, applying `Head` to it yields `Symbol`. The reason for that is that  `Removed["sym"]` still represents a symbol, albeit marked for removal. For code like this:

```
Clear[b];b := a;Remove[a];b
```

you can not, e.g., "resurrect" `a` in `b` with this:

```
b /. Removed[x_] :> ToExpression[x]
```

> `Removed["a"]`

but, since `Removed["a"]` represents a symbol marked for removal, this will work, to at least reconstruct the value of `b`:

```
b /. Cases[b, s_Symbol :> (s :> a), {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]
```

> `a`

You can also analyze which symbols in some expression were `Remove`-d, by something like this:

```
Clear[removedNames];
removedNames[expr_] :=
  Flatten[
    StringCases[
      ToString /@ Union@Cases[expr, _Symbol, Infinity, Heads -> True],
      ShortestMatch["Removed[" ~~ x__ ~~ "]"] :> x]
  ]
```

So that

```
removedNames[OwnValues[y]]
```

> `{"x"}`

#### Summary

So, to summarize:

- `Removed` is not a normal head but a display form.
- When you `Remove` a symbol, `Removed[sym]` still represents this symbol, but being marked for removal. My understanding is that this is still a reference to the symbol table, but it becomes opaque and not bound to the symbol name any more. However, apparently, Mathematica still allows you to manipulate it, pretty much as if you manipulated the normal symbol. In particular, you can, for the purposes of pattern-matching, still count on it being a `Symbol`. This allows us to do some things as if the symbol in question has not been removed, particularly by using local rule substitutions.
- As you demonstrated, you can still change some `...Values` for `Remove`-d symbols with local rules. While it looks like you can reconstruct many of the symbol's properties (except explicit symbol name), I would however limit such uses of these symbols to extreme cases when you need to make some definitions valid in a given Mathematica session.

**EDIT:  one constructive use - catching bugs induced by `Remove`**

Here is one possibly constructive use of the above behavior. `Remove`-ing symbols is dangerous because it subtly invalidates definitions for other symbols which were referencing the symbols being removed. We may wish to know when this happens, but often the effects are silent and insidious. Here is a function which enables one to trigger such events:

```
ClearAll[remove];
SetAttributes[remove, HoldAll];
remove::remvd = "Stymbol `1` was removed!";
remove[s_Symbol, failCode_: Throw[$Failed, remove]] :=
  Module[{defs},
    With[{strsym = ToString[HoldForm[s]]},
       With[{body := (
          Message[remove::remvd , Style[strsym, Red]];
          failCode
           )},
        defs :=
          Module[{},
            OwnValues[s] = HoldPattern[s] :> body;
            UpValues[s] = HoldPattern[_[___, s, ___]] :> body;
          ]]];
    Remove[s];
    defs;];
```

What it does is to assign certain definitions to symbols already after they have been removed, using the behavior discussed above. These definitions execute arbitrary user-defined code when evaluation comes to the `Remove`-d symbol, in most cases (except when the symbols are inside `HoldAllComplete` heads). To augment it, here is a dynamic environment, in which `Remove` will behave that way:

```
ClearAll[withCustomRemove];
SetAttributes[withCustomRemove, HoldAll];
withCustomRemove[code_,failCode_: Throw[$Failed, remove]] :=
  Module[{inRemove},
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{Remove },
     Unprotect[Remove];
     Remove[arg_] /; ! TrueQ[inRemove] :=
         Block[{inRemove = True}, remove[arg,failCode]];
     Protect[Remove];
     code]];
```

and here is an example of use. First, the usual behavior:

```
ClearAll[f, a];
f[x_] := x + a;
g[] := Hold[a];
Remove[a];
{f[1], g[]}
```

> ```
> {1+Removed[a],Hold[Removed[a]]}
> ```

Now, with our functions:

```
withCustomRemove[
   ClearAll[f, a];
   f[x_] := x + a;
   g[] := Hold[a];
   Remove[a];
]
{f[1], g[]}
```

> ```
>   During evaluation of In[78]:= remove::remvd: Stymbol a was removed!
>
>   During evaluation of In[78]:= Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[$Failed,remove]
>            returned to top level. >>
>
>   Hold[Throw[$Failed,remove]]
> ```

One can specify a different behavior to be triggered on such an event. One can also generalize to `Remove` with several arguments. The idea is that you can take the code which is suspicious, and execute it inside `withCustomRemove` - which may often enable you to catch bugs related to attempts to use `Remove`-d symbols.

Comment: Thinking about it using all the information above, the probable implementation is that each symbol is a data structure containing its name, associated values, and a link to the context it belongs to (and the context of course needs a link to the symbol). `Remove` then clears the definitions and removes the symbol from its context (thus clearing the context backlink), but doesn't actually remove the symbol. When printing a symbol, the formatting routine looks at the context to decide whether it has to be printed with the symbol's name, and if there is no context, returns `Removed["name"]`.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, I would think so. I've edited my answer in the meantime and added something similar to what you are saying. My understanding is that the symbol remains in the symbol table, but its reference (handle) is no longer tied to a given symbol (in some context), so it can not be retrieved by the symbol lookup mechanism (which is based on symbol names, including their contexts). But, it can still be manipulated, although we lose the convenience of named symbols.

Comment: As a side note, one of the most amazing things (to me anyway) is that for most of the core language features, including subtleties like this one, we still can get insights and accurate information in accounts 15-20 years old, and not only that, but those serve us very often better than anything that came after. This shows once again that the core language did not change much, which is quite impressive, given that most recent developments in Mathematica were heavily relying on the core language.

Comment: Thinking about the question, and your answer, it seems that a `Removed` symbol is almost identical to a gensym in Common Lisp (or Emacs Lisp), though their purposes for existing are almost totally different. In both Mathematica and Lisp, symbols are complex, flexible data structures, not merely names that have been interned into some global table.

Comment: @Pillsy I hope to understand this comment of yours better one day. Lisp is on my wish list. As far as I understand, gensyms are similar to `Unique` - generated symbols in Mathematica, and are used often to help with scoping issues.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I really recommend it! In any event, the difference has to do with whether the symbol is globally accessible through it's name or not. I'm not sure the best way to explain in more detail in the StackExchange format, though. :-/

Comment: @Pillsy Thanks, I certainly owe it to myself (Lisp), actually for several years already. And yes, SE format is quite restrictive :)

Comment: It's interesting that if `x` refers to `Removed["y"]` then `MatchQ[x, Removed_]` yields `True`, but `x /. Removed[name_] :> name` does not extract the name, `Depth[x]` yields `1` and `AtomQ[x]` yields `True`. But although `Uncompress[Compress[x]]` has visually the same `FullForm` `Removed["y"]`, but its `Head` is now `Removed`, `Depth` is `2`, `AtomQ` is `False` and `/. Removed[name_] :> name` can actually extract the name `"y"`.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Interesting. Looks like a bug to me (the second behavior). The concept, as I understand it, is to have `Removed` as a print form, not as a full-fledged head. So that the symbols that have been removed, are cleared from all definitions, and no longer associated with their names (although, apparently, they can still be used in certain ways, as I outlined in my answer).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin My mistake! Of course, everything matches `Removed_`. I intended to write `MatchQ[a, _Removed]`, which evaluates to `False`.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Indeed. Apparently I wasn't reading carefully either. But what took you so long? :)

Comment: I just got stumbled over removed symbols again, and found this old discussion, and noticed this mistake in my comment.