# Safely nesting RuleDelayed

Tags: replacement

Say I have the following, straightforward-seeming functions:

```
makeARuleDelayed[a_, b_] :=
 With[{anotherRule = makeAnotherRuleDelayed[b]},
  v : a[b] :> ((v == 1 - v) /. anotherRule)];

makeAnotherRuleDelayed[x_] :=
  v : h_[x] :> foo[h, x];
```

If I use them to create a `RuleDelayed`, I get an error message:

> ```
> a[b] /. makeARuleDelayed[a, b]
> ```
>
> RuleDelayed::rhs: Pattern v$:h$_[b] appears on the right-hand side of rule v$:a[b]:>(v$==1-v$/. v$:h$_[b]:>foo[h$,b])
>   .

Examining the result indicates the problem:

```
v$ : a[b] :> (v$ == 1 - v$ /. v$ : h$_[b] :> foo[h$, b])
```

Using this rule fails in about the way you'd expect it to. The only workaround I could think of is adding a `Module` to the body of `makeAnotherRule`:

```
makeAnotherRuleDelayed[x_] :=
 Module[{v},
  v : h_[x] :> foo[h, x]]
```

This doesn't help at all; evidently there must be some sort of magical renaming going on somewhere inside of `RuleDelayed` that truncates the `$nnn` part of the name of the symbol generated by `Module`.

Without being able to nest rules without name clashes, I'm not sure how to go about creating nontrivial rules programmatically.

Comment: It seems to me that you somehow mixed up some of your functions names. Please try running the code you posted after a ClearAll

Comment: @belisarius http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhy7dXWjpAA

Comment: Pillsy I think you've forgotten something.  Where is `makeARule` defined?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a renaming mechanism at work. I think, the "canonical" way to fool it is something like this:

```
makeARuleDelayed[a_, b_] :=
  With[{anotherRule = makeAnotherRuleDelayed[b]},
     v : a[b] :> ((v == 1 - v) /. anotherRule)];

makeAnotherRuleDelayed[x_] :=
  RuleDelayed @@ Hold[v : h_[x], foo[h, x]];
```

By using `RuleDelayed@@Hold`, we fool the renaming mechanism of `With`. Note that this whole issue is because `With` is a scoping construct which cares about inner scoping constructs and possible name collisions. You can use rules instead, which are much more intruding:

```
Clear[makeARuleDelayedAlt];
makeARuleDelayedAlt[a_, b_] :=
    v : a[b] :> ((v == 1 - v) /. makeAnotherRuleDelayed[b])
```

and then keep the original definition for `makeAnotherRuleDelayed`. I discussed these issues in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808).

Comment: Wouldn't you prevent the whole renaming issue by using `Module` instead of `With`?

Comment: @Heike Yes, you are right - it works for this particular case, because it effectively does the same thing: at the time `Module` is resolving its bindings, it can not sense conflicts, because collision only happens at run-time. This is different for `With`, since it does substitutions earlier. But my suggestion is a general method, which will work in any such situation.

Comment: +1 and accepted. The linked explanation of how `With` renames things was very helpful for finding a generalized solution.

Comment: @Pillsy Was happy to help, and thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to the answers left by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7006/531) and [Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7006/531) (and especially the explanation of how `With` renames things that Leonid linked), I was able to come up with a general answer encapsulated by a function which will "sanitize" a `RuleDelayed` and make it "hygenic". First, in a bit of overkill, I use `Unique` and `Remove` to make [truly unique symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4924/531) (like Lisp's [`GENSYM`s](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gensym.htm)):

```
ClearAll[toGensym, makeGensym];

toGensym[s_String] := With[{sym = Unique[s]}, Remove[sym]; sym]

Attributes[makeGensym] = HoldFirst;
makeGensym[s_Symbol] := toGensym[SymbolName@Unevaluated[s] <> "$"];
```

Now I can use `Cases` to collect all the names in a rule which name a pattern on the left-hand side, and replace them with gensyms.

```
ClearAll[Sanitize];
Sanitize[rule : HoldPattern[lhs_ :> rhs_]] :=
 With[{renamings =
    Cases[Hold[lhs],
     HoldPattern[Verbatim[Pattern][s_Symbol, _]] :>
      (HoldPattern[s] -> makeGensym[s]),
     Infinity,
     Heads -> True]},
  rule /. renamings];
```

Now I can just plug in `Sanitize` when I want to nest programmatically created rules:

```
ClearAll[makeARuleDelayed, makeAnotherRuleDelayed, a, b, foo];

makeARuleDelayed[a_, b_] :=
 With[{anotherRule = Sanitize@makeAnotherRuleDelayed[b]},
  v : a[b] :> ((v == 1 - v) /. anotherRule)];

makeAnotherRuleDelayed[x_] :=
 v : h_[x] :> foo[h, x];
```

I no longer get any error messages, though the resulting rules aren't really fit for human consumption anymore:

> ```
> makeARuleDelayed[a, b]
> ```

```
v$: a[b] :> (v$== 1 - v$ /. Removed[v$$75]: (Removed[h$$74]:_)[b] :> 
 foo[Removed[h$$74],b])
```

> ```
> a[b] /. makeARuleDelayed[a, b]
> ```

```
foo[a, b] == 1 - foo[a, b]
```

Comment: Good stuff - +1. I once wrote a [tiny framework](https://gist.github.com/1683497), which is somewhat similar in spirit but works the other way around - it tries to cure the leaks of the Mathematica lexical scoping (the latter exist because it is actually an emulation of lexical scoping) - I thought you might be interested.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks for the link. I am, indeed, interested. :)

Comment: Sure, no problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Does this do what you desire?

```
makeARuleDelayed[a_, b_] := 
 v : a[b] :> ((v == 1 - v) /. #) & @ makeAnotherRuleDelayed[b]

makeAnotherRuleDelayed[x_] := v : h_[x] :> foo[h, x];

a[b] /. makeARuleDelayed[a, b]
```

> ```
> foo[a, b] == 1 - foo[a, b]
> ```