# How to check if a database connection is open?

Tags: pattern-matching, databaselink, expression-test

```
In[32]:= SQLConnections[]

Out[32]= {SQLConnection["db", 1, "Closed", "<>"], 
 SQLConnection["db", 2, "Closed", "<>"], 
 SQLConnection["db", 3, "Open", "Catalog" -> "db",
   "ReadOnly" -> True]}

In[33]:= Cases[SQLConnections[], SQLConnection[__, "Open", __]]

Out[33]= {}
```

doesn't work.  Why it doesn't match the one open connection expression?

Comment: `SQLConnections[] // FullForm` shows why the pattern matching fails.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @MikeHoneychurch observes, the formatted form of an `SQLConnection` expression:

```
SQLConnection["db", 3, "Open", "Catalog" -> "db", "ReadOnly" -> True]
```

differs from its `FullForm`:

```
SQLConnection[JDBC[...], JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject18126325894086657, 1, ...]
```

Pattern matching uses the `FullForm`.

One way to work around this is to convert the expression into its formatted form prior to pattern-matching:

```
Cases[
  Format[#] /. FormatValues[SQLConnection] & /@ SQLConnections[]
, SQLConnection[__, "Open", __]
]

(* {SQLConnection["db", 3, "Open", "Catalog" -> "db", "ReadOnly" -> True]} *)
```

If one has no objection to exploiting knowledge of the internal representation of an `SQLConnection`, then another option is to test the JDBC connection object directly:

```
Needs["JLink`"]

Cases[
  SQLConnections[]
, SQLConnection[_, c_, ___] /; JavaObjectQ[c] && c =!= Null && !c@isClosed[]
]

(* {SQLConnection["db", 3, "Open", "Catalog" -> "db", "ReadOnly" -> True]} *)
```

Comment: +1, converting to formatted form is clever. Also, testing for being a Java object reference is clearly better than testing for a symbol being removed, since the latter is a deeper level implementation detail than the former.

Comment: Great, but.... If I kill Mathematica's database connection in the database server and apply the JLink answer, it is still reported as open even though it is broken. If I try to use it I get: "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
Communications link failure".

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I'm afraid DatabaseLink is no different from most other database client protocols: an "open" connection does not imply a "usable" connection.  The only way to know whether a database connection is still alive (as opposed to merely open) is to attempt to perform an operation on it.  The common practice is to attempt a trivial query like `SELECT 1` (or `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` in Oraclespeak).

Comment: "SELECT 1" is a good idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

conn = DatabaseLink`OpenSQLConnection[ 
   DatabaseLink`JDBC[ "MySQL(Connector/J)", 
    "localhost:3306/railfreight"], "Username" -> "", 
   "Password" -> ""]

(* SQLConnection[1, "Open", "Catalog" -> "railfreight", 
 "TransactionIsolationLevel" -> "RepeatableRead"]*)
```

But when you check out the `FullForm` (removed password info):

```
FullForm[conn]

(* SQLConnection[JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)","localhost:3306/railfreight"],JLink`Objects`vm1`JavaObject121074792529921,2,Rule["Catalog",Automatic],Rule["Description",None],Rule["Location",None],Rule["Name",None],Rule["Password",""],Rule["Properties",List[]],Rule["ReadOnly",Automatic],Rule["RelativePath",False],Rule["TransactionIsolationLevel",Automatic],Rule["UseConnectionPool",Automatic],Rule["Username",""],Rule["Version",None]] *)
```

Similarly when you close the connection:

```
CloseSQLConnection[conn]
FullForm[conn]

(* SQLConnection[JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)","localhost:3306/railfreight"],Removed["JavaObject341542795476993"],1,Rule["Catalog",Automatic],Rule["Description",None],Rule["Location",None],Rule["Name",None],Rule["Password",""],Rule["Properties",List[]],Rule["ReadOnly",Automatic],Rule["RelativePath",False],Rule["TransactionIsolationLevel",Automatic],Rule["UseConnectionPool",Automatic],Rule["Username",""],Rule["Version",None]] *)
```

So based on that I think this is worth a try:

```
Cases[SQLConnections[], SQLConnection[_, Except[_Removed], __]]
```

Comment: The problem is that the head `Removed` is not really a normal head, see e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/what-is-the-story-with-removed-symbols/4924#4924). In particular, direct pattern-matching attempts with `Removed` don't work. So, good idea, but I guess the realization should be more tricky (no time now to try).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks. I hadn't previously seen that discussion you have linked to.

Comment: Actually, one can use functions similar to `removedNames` of that linked answer, to check whether or not the symbols has been removed. Something like `SetAttributes[removedQ, HoldAll];removedQ[s_Symbol] :=  StringMatchQ[ToString[Unevaluated@s], "Removed[" ~~ __ ~~ "]"]`, and then test as `Cases[SQLConnections[], SQLConnection[_, Except[_?removedQ], __]]`. I think this should work. In any case, +1 for finding the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I just checked the documentation in V10 and accidentally stumbled upon a built in command:
`SQLConnectionOpenQ[conn]`
This seems to do the trick.