# Remove Removed From Output

Tags: symbols, clear

How might I remove `Removed[..]` symbols from the output of an expression?

For example

```
Clear[b]; b := Sin[a + a]; Remove[a];
b
```

> Sin[2 Removed[a]]

Now as discussed in [the story of removed symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/what-is-the-story-with-removed-symbols), `Removed[a]` aren't functions with `Heads` but symbols with special forms.

This works for catching the symbols.

```
b /. Cases[b, s_Symbol :> (s :> a), {0, Infinity}, Heads -> True]
```

But how might I generalize this to all symbols?

Here is my evolving code.  `ToString[s] == Removed` should likely be generalized, but more importantly I can't seem to prevent `s:>newHead` from going unevaluated.

```
Replace[b,
 HoldPattern[s_Symbol] :>
  With[{newHead = If[ToString[s] === "Removed[a]"
        a, b
      ]},
    s :> newHead /; True], Infinity
 ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use something like this:

```
b /. s_Symbol /; ! StringQ@MakeBoxes@s :>
       Symbol @ StringTake[ToString@s, {9, -2}]
```

> ```
> Sin[2 a]
> ```

If `a` has a value and you don't want `a` to evaluate in the replacement you'll need something more.  This is the best I could think of:

```
a = "Fail!";  (* this should not appear in the output *)

Module[{hold},
 SetAttributes[hold, HoldAll];
 Hold @@ {b} /. s_Symbol /; ! StringQ@MakeBoxes@s :>
    RuleCondition@ToExpression[StringTake[ToString@s, {9, -2}], InputForm, hold] /.
  {hold[x_] :> x}
]
```

> ```
> Hold[Sin[2 a]]
> ```

`Hold @@ {b}` is just an example.