# Remove versus ClearAll

Tags: functions, evaluation, memory, guidelines

What is the difference between `Remove` and `ClearAll`?

I thought that "*not being recognized by Mathematica*", which is the effect of [`Remove`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Remove.html), meant that there would be no "*values, definitions, attributes, messages, and defaults associated with symbols*", which is the effect of [`ClearAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClearAll.html). That naive equivalence is wrong as shown by the different output out of these two lines:

```
b := a; Remove[a]; b
b := a; ClearAll[a]; b
```

Which side effects of `Remove` are not shared by `ClearAll` (and viceversa)?

Comment: Related: [How do I clear all user defined symbols?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols), especially rm-rf's [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols/884#884).

Comment: It seems that a symbol is "introduced" when it is first used, even if it is only as rhs. "introduction" not being the same as "definition", which I understand as including an OwnValue, DownValue, etc. With this distinction, `Remove` does everything that `ClearAll` does AND it also removes the "introduction" of that symbol. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, `Temporary` symbols are "removed" not "cleaned"...

Comment: Remove removes the symbol, ClearAll does not.

Comment: Here's a practical difference: `f[a]=1`.  Now `f[a]` gives `1`;  `ClearAll[a]` does nothing in practice, as `a` had no definitions, attributes, etc.  Now try `Remove[a]` and evaluate `f[a]` again.

Comment: Read also [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/what-is-the-story-with-removed-symbols).

Answer (score 20):

`ClearAll` clears all definitions associated with the symbol. However, the symbol remains in the symbol table, so all references to that symbol from other symbols (their definitions) remain fully valid. The symbol can then acquire new rules or other global properties associated with it.

`Remove` removes the symbol from the symbol table. More precisely, it removes the association between the symbol name and the actual symbol. In any case, the symbol becomes unusable (normally. There are ways to still use it, will mention that below). The same is true for all references to that symbol from other symbols, which silently become invalid. What this means is that by using `Remove`, one can subtly invalidate the code in ways which will be very hard to track (but see the link below for some suggestions here). For more details on certain interesting properties of `Remove`-d symbols, I refer to [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/what-is-the-story-with-removed-symbols).

In terms of their usage, the two functions are quite different. `ClearAll` is a function intended for quite frequent and general use. `Remove`, however, I view as a much more specialist and lower-level function. In fact, I would advise against using `Remove` unless you know exactly what you are doing. It does have a number of advanced uses, but normally the only use which comes to mind is to remove an accidental shadow symbol during the interactive work.

Answer (score 10):

Besides destroying the symbol itself, the main side effect of `Remove` that is not shared by ClearAll is what happens to expressions containing a removed symbol.

```
a = {x, y};
ClearAll[x, y];a
```

> ```
> {x, y}
> ```

```
Remove[y]; a
```

> ```
> {x, Removed[y]}
> ```