# Protected Tag Error

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following code:

```
ANCL={{0, 25, 0, 0}, {-((36 k1)/41), -((36 k2)/41), 544/5125, -24.0179}, {(900 k1)/41, 11.6625 k2, -(544/205), -24.5524}, {11.6625 k1, 11.6625 k2, 0.0764667, -2.42273}}
Table[Eigenvalues[ANCL], {{k1, {0.001, 0.01, 0.1}}, {k2, {0.01, 0.1, 1}}}];
p = ListPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ %, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
PlotRange -> {{-5, 0}, {-25, 25}}, ImagePadding -> 40, 
AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.02]]];
Show[p]
```

I get the error *"Tag List in {k1,{0.001,0.01,0.1}} is Protected."*.

Now I use `Quit[]` before starting the evaluation. Also, I am really not defining any functions here. The intention is just to evaluate eigenvalues for varying $k_1$ and $k_2$. I checked the other similar questions but I think I do not have the same issue.

P.S. I edited the code to include `ANCL`.

Comment: `ANCL` is not defined so we can't check that a problem doesn't arise there however it does look like your `Table` syntax is off a little. You don't need to embrace both the `k1` and `k2` lists in another `List`. Check the docs for `Table`.

Comment: You should see `k1` and `k2` change from blue to turquoise in doing so (in the more recent versions of MMA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good clearing practices](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113783/good-clearing-practices)

Comment: Try `ClearAll` and run your definition of `ANCL` and your code again.

Comment: @JHM I think I already mentioned that I have seen the ClearAll posts...It does not work. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: @Quantum_Oli In the documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html here it says in the second last demonstration (before details) that for evaluating at specific values Table[expr,{i,{i1,i2,...}}]. It si given for one variable so I modified it for 2. Please let me know if it is still incorrect

Comment: There appears to be a syntax error in the iterators of your `Table` command. Try with `Table[Eigenvalues[ANCL], {k1, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01}, {k2, 0.01, 1, 0.1}]`

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [(11982)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11982)

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with the code in question.

- Multiple variables in `Table` need to be enclosed in separate lists i.e: not `Table[expr,{{var1,specs},{var2specs}}]` but rather `Table[expr,{var1,specs},{var2,specs}]`. This is the source of the protected tag error.
- `ListPlot` needs a list of coordinates `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}` rather than the matrix provided as an output of `Table` in order to plot correctly.

With those elements in mind, let me provide you with an alternative visualisation for your problems, using `Manipulate`:

```
ANCL[k1_,k2_] := {{0, 25, 0, 0}, {-((36 k1)/41), -((36 k2)/41), 
   544/5125, -24.0179}, {(900 k1)/41,11.6625 k2, -(544/205), -24.5524},
   {11.6625 k1, 11.6625 k2,0.0764667, -2.42273}}
```

I write the matrix as a function of $k1$ and $k2$ for convenience (don't forget to clear the previous definition of ANCL).

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  Transpose[{Re@Eigenvalues[ANCL[k1, k2]], 
    Im@Eigenvalues[ANCL[k1, k2]]}], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}]
 , {k1, {0.001, 0.01, 0.1}}, {k2, {0.01, 0.1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Or maybe you wanted all the eigenvalues on the same plot, in which case:

```
ListPlot[Flatten[
  Table[Transpose[{Re@Eigenvalues[ANCL[k1, k2]], 
     Im@Eigenvalues[ANCL[k1, k2]]}], {k1, {0.001, 0.01, 
     0.1}}, {k2, {0.01, 0.1, 1}}], 2], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}]
```

Be mindful of the level specification ($2$) in the argument of `Flatten`.

[image]

#### Edit: With differenciated eigenvalues and tooltips!

```
ListPlot[MapThread[
  Tooltip, {Flatten[
    Table[Transpose[{Re@Eigenvalues[ANCL[k1, k2]], 
       Im@Eigenvalues[ANCL[k1, k2]]}], {k1, {0.001, 0.01, 
       0.1}}, {k2, {0.01, 0.1, 1}}], 1], 
   Map[ToString, 
    Flatten[Table[{k1, 
       k2}, {k1, {0.001, 0.01, 0.1}}, {k2, {0.01, 0.1, 1}}], 1]]}], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02]], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  SwatchLegend[
   Map[ToString, 
    Flatten[Table[{k1, 
       k2}, {k1, {0.001, 0.01, 0.1}}, {k2, {0.01, 0.1, 1}}], 1]], 
   LegendLabel -> Text["{k1,k2}"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Great but can you add how to make them different color. I can imagine it won't be easy with two variables. But if lets say I chose to fix and vary other over a range, then how can I have a colorbar that represents it. I know the commands but getting the syntax wrong always frustrates me

Comment: Seeing the `Directive[Red]` in your code I thought you wanted all the datapoints to be red. If you take off the `Red` in the `Directive` and `Flatten` at level 1 instead you will get each set of 4 eigenvalues coloured differently.

Comment: I've added legends and tooltips. I hope this motivates you to get a sense of the formatting syntax.