# What's the difference between $Context<>"*" and "`*"?

Tags: syntax, contexts, function-comparison

When set context unique to this notebook:

```
ClearAll @@ { $Context<>"*" } 

Clear["`*"]
```

can both clear the variables I assigned. I just wonder what's the difference between them? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: An obvious difference is one uses `ClearAll` and the other uses `Clear`.  Fixing that, can you give an example where one of these inputs gives a different result than the other?

Comment: It seems to me they always take the same effect in one notebook.

Comment: Are you asking about `Clear` vs `ClearAll` or `$Context<>"*"` vs ``"`*"``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `Clear` vs. `ClearAll`

Is answered here: [Good clearing practices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113783/5478)

#### `$Context<>"*"` vs. `` "`*" ``:

99% of the time it is the same thing.

See tutorial/Contexts: "`` `name ``  a symbol in the current context"

See also ref / ClearAll / Examples / Applications / 2nd example

So how can it be different? If it is **defined and evaluated** in a different context than the context of the **moment of using it**. Here is an example:

```
BeginPackage["MyContext`"]

ClearMe[] := ClearAll  @ clearSpec1;

clearSpec1 = $Context <> "*";
clearSpec2 = "`*";

EndPackage[]
```

Now, if you call `ClearMe[]` it will correctly clear `` MyContext`* `` even though the current context is probably `` Global` ``. Had `clearSpec2` been used you would clear `` Global` ``.

Ok, pretty artificial example but you get the point.