# Is there a fast method of clearing symbols in the sub-contexts named by other symbols?

Tags: packages, contexts

When writing packages I met the following problem. The way I name helper functions is like

```
BeginPackage["test`"];
ClearAll@@Names[$Context<>"*"];

test0[]:=0;
test0`helper1[]:=0;
test0`helper2[]:=0;
...

EndPackage[];
```

When `` Get["test`"] `` the public symbols under `` test` ``  will be cleared by `ClearAll@@Names[$Context<>"*"];` but the symbols under `` test0` ``  are remained unchanged.

I need a fast way of searching and clearing all symbols under the contexts like `` symbol`* ``, where `symbol`s are from some specific contexts.

To set up and test the problem, the following codes generate 10 symbols for each of the 200 sub-contexts:

```
BeginPackage["test`"];

ToExpression["
    test"<>#1<>"[]=0;
    test"<>#1<>"`a"<>#2<>"[]=0;
"]&@@@Flatten[
    Outer[List,ToString/@Range[200],ToString/@Range[10]],
    1
];

EndPackage[];
```

```
Names["test`*"]//Shallow
Names["test1`*"]
Names["test2`*"]
```

[image]

The direct way of clearing these helper functions is like

```
clearHelper[contexts__] :=
    (
        {contexts}//Map[Names[#<>"*"]&]//
            Map[ClearAll@Evaluate[#<>"`*",#<>"`*`*"]&,#,{2}]&;
    );
```

which is rather inefficient

```
test1`a1[]
clearHelper["test`"]//Timing
test1`a1[]
```

[image]

In some days earlier I used another method of managing helper functions: each symbol with helper functions is tagged by

```
test0//hasHelpers
```

where `hasHelpers` will store `test0` into a public list `$hasHelpers` shared by all packages. Then I abandoned this method since frequently appending symbols to list will slow down `Get` and I'm tired of adding `test0//hasHelpers`.

Is there some clever way of solving this problem?

---

Or are there editors or IDEs that can auto-complete contexts? e.g. symbols like `` test0`helper1[] `` within `` BeginPackage["test`"] `` or `` Begin["`Private`"] `` will be parsed into `*.wl` as

```
test`test0`helper1[]
```

automatically?

Comment: Is ``Names["test*`*"]`` adequate?  That syntax is also supported by `Clear` and `Remove`.

Comment: @WReach No, the symbols in a package ``test` `` are certainly not fitted into ``test*`* ``. A feature I forgot to say is that the association from symbols like `testn` to the contexts ``testn` `` can be quite sparse since only a few functions need helper functions. And the naive inefficient function `clearHelper` just traverses this association one by one.

Comment: Maybe you dismissed the first comment too quickly? With ``Names["test*`*"]`` I get ``{test0`helper1, test0`helper2, test0}``. Note the last one, `test0`, which is in the ``test` `` context.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to follow the standard way: `BeginPackage["Test\`"]; test0; Begin["\`Private\`"] test0[]:=helper1[] ... .... End[]; EndPackage[]`. Then you could just do `ClearAll["\`*", "\`*\`*"]` and still only `test0` is exported from the package.

Comment: @user293787 the functions in ``test` `` are not named as `test0` in REAL examples.

Comment: @Kuba I don't know which style is "standard". For example there are systems symbols like ``System`SparseArray `` with lots of ``SparseArray`* ``. I prefer to name `helper1` as ``test`test0`helper0 `` or ``test`private`test0`helper0 `` so that the names of helper functions for different public functions will not be conflict. But ``test`test0`helper0 `` is too lengthy and then I choose ``test0`helper0 ``.

Comment: @Kuba For example, if two public functions `f1` and `f2` call the same private function `helper0`, I prefer to make them decoupled: `f1` calls ``f1`helper0 `` and `f2` calls ``f2`helper0 ``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have changed the code styles, roughly following from https://github.com/WolframResearch/PacletCICD-Examples-AdvancedSample

For the original problem, the following function is faster

```
clearHelperFunction[contexts__,level_Integer:1] :=
    Module[ {helperList,helperContextList},
        helperContextList =
            Quiet[NestList[#<>"`*"&,#<>"`*",level-1],{StringJoin::string}]/.{all_:>Hold[all&]}//ReleaseHold;
        helperList =
            {contexts}//Map[Names[#<>"*"]&]//Map[helperContextList,#,{2}]&//Flatten;
        helperList = 
            DeleteCases[helperList,Alternatives@@`clearHelper`exceptionList];
        ClearAll@@helperList
    ];
clearHelperFunction[] :=
    StringCases[$ContextPath,StartOfString~~selfContext~~___]//Flatten//Apply[clearHelperFunction];
`clearHelper`exceptionList = {
    "FE`*"
};
```

[image]

There are quite tricky issues concerning `Names, ClearAll, ...`, e.g.

```
SeedRandom[1]

data=RandomWord[100];

data//Map[ClearAll]//Quiet//RepeatedTiming//First
data//Apply[ClearAll]//Quiet//RepeatedTiming//First
```

[image]

see also [Why Names will search all subcontexts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279719/why-names-will-search-all-subcontexts)

---

I'd also like to compare the different code editors and styles I have tried.

#### Editors

- notebook, inconvenient for multi-file project;
- vscode + Wolfram extension, the formatting functionality is a bit weird;
- eclipse + Wolfram workbench, outdated, e.g. do not support `|->` and non-English characters

Currently I use the last one.

#### Style

- main function `foo` with helper functions  `` foo`h1, foo`h2, ... `` - the approach in this question. This is really bad but the drawbacks can be cured:

  - symbols can collide. There can be different versions of `foo`, then the helpers collide.
  - hard to manage.
  - **Solution:** use `$ContextAliases` to resolve the context `` foo` `` to `` package`foo`Private` ``. But, it seems that in version 13.3 `$ContextAliases` is quite slow.
- main function `foo` with helper functions  `` `foo`h1, `foo`h2, ... ``. This could be the most convenient approach. Drawback:

  - Wolfram workbench does not support renaming symbols starting from backtick like `` `foo`h1 ``
- multiple subcontext in single file by `Begin, End`.
  As pointed by @kuba, this can cause confusion and is hard to rename.
- single subcontext for each file, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176591/86893 https://github.com/WolframResearch/PacletCICD-Examples-AdvancedSample. This could be the best approach without undocumented functionalities or third-party paclets. see also another style [What to be aware when using new-style package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184711/what-to-be-aware-when-using-new-style-package)

Answer (score 3):

Start with [what is a package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29325/5478).

Then you can do

```
ClearAll["`*`", "`*`*"]
```

`` "`*" `` is a shorthand for `$Context<>"*"`
and `` "`*`*" `` will find even 'deeper' symbols like `` test1`a`b`c`foo ``

Related: [189660](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189660/5478)

If you insist on a private context specific to an exported function then the final code can be:

```
BeginPackage["Test`"]

  ClearAll["`*","`*`*"]

  test0::usage = ""
  test1::usage = ""

Begin["`test0`"]


  test0[]:= helper01[];

  helper01[]:=0;

End[]


Begin["`test1`"]


  test1[]:= helper11[];

  helper11[]:=2;

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

```
test0[]
test1[]
```

> 0
> 2

Notice that you could have `helper01` and `helper11` called both `helper` and it would work just fine because they are created in different contexts:

```
DownValues@test0
```

> `` {HoldPattern[test0[]] :> Test`test0`helper01[]} ``

But I don't think this is a good idea because it could be confusing to have the same name within a single file.