# Why Names will search all subcontexts?

Tags: performance-tuning, symbols, contexts

My version is 13.2. When debugging I came across this peculiar feature of `Names`.

Starting with a fresh kernel, define
[image]

Then `` Names[{"context`*"}] `` will search all subcontexts while `` Names["context`*"] `` only search the first level, and the former causes unnecessary slow-down (according to the purpose).
[image]

In my experience, the later behaviour is the common one for other symbols, e.g.
[image]

Is this documented somewhere? (I read the documentation of `Names` but didn't find.)
Are there any other symbols sharing similar behaviours with `Names`?

Comment: Names docs say, in details & options, that "`Names["context\`*"]` lists all symbols in the specified context", so it is a special case.

Comment: @Kuba My question is that ``Names[{ctx`*}] `` will search all subcontext under ``ctx` ``. I didn't find any explanation in the doc.

Comment: ``Names[{f`*}]`` searches all names that match this. There is no such thing as a subcontext, ``f`x`x`` is just a symbol `x` in a context ``f`x` ``. ``Names[f`*]`` would return the same but they made a special case, and documented it, that it will look in ``f` `` only, so no ``f`x` `` etc.