# What is the difference between Clear and ClearAll?

Tags: symbols, clear

I'm reading *Mathematica Programming* by Leonid Shifrin. And it said

> `ClearAll` serves to clear all definitions (including attributes) for a given symbol (or symbols), and not to clear definitions of all global symbols in the system (it is a common mistake to mix these two things).

So what is the difference between these two things, which are a given symbol and a global symbol?

Comment: The "all" is the important part here: if you e.g. define `f[x_] := x^2` and `g[x_] := x^3`, and then evaluate `ClearAll[f]`, then `f`'s definitions are cleared, but `g`'s definitions are left untouched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leonid, I think, was cautioning against using `ClearAll[]` alone in hopes that this would clear all definitions and provide a "clean slate". The closest equivalent to that might be `` ClearAll["Global`*"] ``, although that still only clears user-generated definitions and not those in other contexts. Or you could use `Quit[]` or the menu entries to quit the currently running kernel and start afresh, for a more thorough cleanup that will forget all transient definitions, including packages loaded, modifications to other contexts, et cetera.

In other words: `ClearAll` is a "more powerful" version of `Clear`, but it still works only *for the specific symbol(s) provided* in its input. It does not, perhaps confusingly, "clear all symbols" in the session. Instead, it "clears all properties" of a given symbol.

---

It may be worth mentioning, for completeness, that `Clear` clear values of symbols, but it does not clear attributes, messages, or defaults associated with them; `ClearAll` clears those as well. You may also be interested in the discussion in [Good clearing practices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113783/27951) on this forum.

Comment: This code is very effective Clear["Global`*"]

Comment: @PRG Too effective, imho. But see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-do-i-clear-all-user-defined-symbols, too.

Answer (score 3):

Let me rewrite the paragraph that you quote:

*In `ClearAll` the "all" stands for "all definitions". It does not stand for "all symbols". Therefore calling `ClearAll[f]` means to "clear all definitions associated to the symbol `f`".*

Two examples:

- Suppose you first define `f` to be the squaring function as in `f[x_]:=x^2` and you then call `ClearAll[f]`, then `f` will no longer be the squaring function, so `f[12]` will not give `144` but `f[12]`. Other symbols `g`, `h`, ... that you may have defined are not affected by `ClearAll[f]`.
- `ClearAll[]` does not mean "clear all symbols", but it means "clear all definitions of no symbol", so it does nothing at all.

To clarify what Leonid Shifrin means by "given symbol": If you call `ClearAll[f]` then `f` is the "given symbol". If you call `ClearAll[f,g]` then `f` and `g` are the "given symbols".

By contrast, you should read "all global symbols" as simply "all symbols". The qualification "global" refers to [contexts](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#27982) which is a slightly more advanced topic that you can ignore at first.

**Note.** In this answer I used "all definitions" as an abbreviation for "all definitions, all attributes, all messages" and so on.