# Have the bugs with Remove["Global`*"] returned in 11.3?

Tags: function-construction

This works fine:

```
data = {{97, 63, 88}, {1, 20, 35}, {174, 42, 122}, {172, 152, 
   18993}, {7, 2, 2}, {173, 86, 112}};
DeleteCases[data, {u_, v_, w_} /; u <= 10]
```

But this does not always work:

```
Remove["Global`*"]; data = {{97, 63, 88}, {1, 20, 35}, {174, 42, 
   122}, {172, 152, 18993}, {7, 2, 2}, {173, 86, 112}};
DeleteCases[data, {u_, v_, w_} /; u <= 10]
```

Comment: ``Global`data`` is created during parsing and then removed during evaluation of your first line

Comment: looks like a duplicate: [Why does removing a function and defining it on the same line not work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128818/5478)

Comment: What if you enter a return character between `Remove[...];` and the `data` definition?

Comment: @user6014 each line is parsed separately so it will work.

Comment: @kuba Yup. Not all users are familiar with the "parsing" and the evaluation procedure, so being a little more explicit about it may help someone who isn't an expert and has this issue

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions fixed the problem!